# linking dmalloc-5.5.2 with opensource application with logging causes the application to crashin OpenWRT 21.02

Tags: openwrt, collectd, dmalloc

```
collectd -C /var/run/collectd.conf
configfile: wordexp (/var/run/collectd.conf) failed.
Unable to read config file /var/run/collectd.conf.
Error: Reading the config file failed!
Read the syslog for details
```

Dmalloc library is linked via CFLAGS and LDLAGS in the collectd makefile. dmalloc is not working as  expected and causing the application to crash.